# Calculate $E(X)$ and the PMF of Number of Flips to Get $2$ Consecutive Heads or Tails with a Coin Flips

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Consider flipping a fair coin until either two consecutive heads appear or two consecutive tails appear, and let $X$ denote the total number of flips required to obtain the $2nd$ consecutive heads or the $2nd$ consecutive tails.

(a) Give the $pmf$ of $X$.

(b) Give the value of $E(X)$.

**Attempted Solution:**

(a) We need to have a sequence of tosses of length $n-1$ of the form HTHTHT,..., or THTHTH,..., and the probability that each sequence happens for $n - 1$ tosses is $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. So the total probability of the two sequences is $\frac{2}{2^{n-1}}$. But then the next toss must be the same as the $(n-1)$th toss giving

$$\frac{2}{2^{n-1}}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$

I have then that $P(X=n)$ = $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ where $n \geq 2$ so the $pmf$ would be

$$p_X(n) = \begin{cases} {\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} & \text{$n \geq 2$}  \\  
{0} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

(b) Then would the $E(X)$ just be $\sum_2^\infty{\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}} = 3$?

Comment: Your answers are correct. It would be nice if you pasted your own answers including how you got them.

Comment: Edited it. Would it be better form to have $p_{X}(x)$ rather than $p_{X}(n)$  or does it not really matter?

Comment: I think the PMF is the easy one. The solution of the sum isn't trivial (Though not so hard).

Comment: I used an infinite sum calculator. I'm actually not sure how I'd solve that by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Probability Mass Function (PMF)

Let $ X $ be the random variable that counts the number of tosses until we get two successive tosses of the same type.

We're basically dealing with Binary Chains which each chain has the probability of $ \frac{1}{ {2}^{n} } $ where $ n $ is the length of the chain.

The probability $ P \left( X = n \right) $ means having $ n - 1 $ chain of alternating tails and heads (HTHTHTH or THTHTHT for $ n = 7 $). Since there are 2 of those (One starts with H the other with T) their probability is $ \frac{2}{ {2}^{n} } $. The probability to have in the $ n $ -th toss H or T as required is $ \frac{1}{2} $ hence the Probability Mass Function is given by:

$$ {P}_{X} \left( n \right) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{ {2}^{n - 1} } & n \geq 2 \\
0 & n \leq 1
\end{cases} $$

### The Expected Value

#### Solution 001

By definition the expected value is given by:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} n {P}_{X} \left( n \right) = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n - 1}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n + 1}{ {2}^{n} } = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ {2}^{n} } + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n} } $$

Now, the first term $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ {2}^{n} } $ is  a geometric series and it is known that $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ {2}^{n} } = 1 $.
Looking at the second term:

$$ {S} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n} } \Rightarrow \frac{S}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n} } = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n + 1} } = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n - 1}{ {2}^{n} } $$

Now one could use another trick:

$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{S}{2} & = S - \frac{S}{2} \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n} } - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n - 1}{ {2}^{n} } \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n}{ {2}^{n} } - \frac{n - 1}{ {2}^{n} } \right) \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ {2}^{n} } = 1 \\
& \Rightarrow S = 2
\end{align*} $$

Which implies $ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ {2}^{n} } + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ {2}^{n} } = 1 + 2 = 3 $.

#### Solution 002

By examining the term $ P \left( X \geq n \right) $:

$$ \begin{array} \\
P \left( X \geq 1 \right) & = & P \left( X = 1 \right)  & + & P \left( X = 2 \right)  & + & P \left( X = 3 \right) + \cdots \\
P \left( X \geq 2 \right) & = &            &   & P \left( X = 2 \right)  & + & P \left( X = 3 \right) + \cdots \\
P \left( X \geq 3 \right) & = &            &   &             &   & P \left( X = 3 \right) + \cdots \\
\end{array} $$

One could see (Summing along the columns) that:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P \left( X \geq n \right) = 1 P \left( X = 1 \right) + 2 P \left( X = 2 \right) + 3 P \left( X = 3 \right) + \cdots + n P \left( X = n \right) = \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] $$

The term $ P \left( X \geq n \right) $ is the event of having $ n - 1 $ alternating chain as above. Namely:

$$ P \left( X \geq n \right) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{ {2}^{n - 2} } & n \geq 2 \\
1 & n \leq 1
\end{cases} $$

This implies:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P \left( X \geq n \right) = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \ldots = 3 $$